# SQL inner join on two colums

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

If i had two database tables

`users` -> `(id, username)`

and

`messages` -> `(msg_id, sender_id, rec_id, text)`

and they both joind on `users.id = messages.sender_id` and also on `users.id = messages.rec_id` so how i can print out results as follow

```
msg_id | sender  |  reciver  | text 
------------------------------------
1      |  david  |  michael  |  hello friend
2      |  eva    |  robert   |  pick me up
```

I've try this

```
SELECT users.*, messages.* 
  FROM messages 
  INNER JOIN users 
  ON users.id = messages.sender_id 
  AND users.id = messages.rec_id
```

but it seems not working as i want .. so any idea

**update** i ment by it deosn't seems to be working, that it gives the sender and reciver name are the same which is wrong !!

```
msg_id | sender  |  reciver  | text 
------------------------------------
1      |  david  |  david  |  hello friend
2      |  eva    |  eva    |  pick me up
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Post some input data for your users and messages tables

Comment: You're comparing both item from messages to users.id. Shouldn't be two different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to join multiple times

```
SELECT users1.*, users2.*,messages.* 
  FROM messages 
  INNER JOIN users1 
  ON users1.id = messages.sender_id 
  INNER JOIN users2 
  AND users2.id = messages.rec_id
```

Comment: ... doh. Head in the clouds. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need two `join`s:

```
SELECT m.*, us.username as sender_name, ur.username as receiver_nae
FROM messages m JOIN
     users us
     ON us.id = m.sender_id JOIN
     users ur
     ON ur.id = m.rec_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current condition, the user id is equal to both the sender and the receiver id, meaning you will only query messages someone sent himself - which is probably not what you want to achieve. Instead, you can join on `users` twice, once for the sender and once for the receiver:

```
SELECT m.msg_id, s.username AS sender, r.username AS receiver, m.text
FROM   messages m
JOIN   users s ON m.sender_id = s.id
JOIN   users r ON m.rec_id = r.id
```